# How to initialize and use passport for different kinds of users?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am not exactly sure how to ask this question, so it may seem a little absurd!

I am developing an application using Node and Express (middleware). I've also used Passport (Local) for authentication. 
Regarding the business of my application, I need to manage two kinds of users.

**Definition**

**Application users**: people who use the application.

**Administrators**: people who manage the content of application.

Now, I used passport (Local) for authenticating the application users. Therefore, I've called my passport-setup in "**app**". The current setup knows the application users' table and works fine. However, for administrators there is another collection which needs to be queried. **Question**: How can I setup tow different collections using passport? Let me show you some code to illustrate the situation.

**app.js**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var passport = require('passport');
var setupPassport = require('./setup-passport');
//Some code here and then
setupPassport();
```

**setupPassport**

```
module.exports = function () {  

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {       

        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){

        User.findById(id,function(err,user){            

            done(err,user);
        });
    });
};
//And 

passport.use('login',new localStrategy(function(username,password,done){



    User.findOne({userName:username},function(err,user){

        if(err){         

            return done(err);
        }

        if(!user){           

            return done(null,false,{message:'The username has not been found!'});
        }

        user.checkPassword(password,function(err,isMatch){
        //...
```

As you can see, the config has been set for application users. What if I want to set another collection for administrators? Is there any solution for setup passport for different collections ? Both users are going to use the same application concurrently, so both can login and logout.

**A likely but ugly solution**

I have been thinking about putting all users information in a single collection, though I am sure it is not nice!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a field into a schema that takes in a boolean. Something like

```
admin:{
type: Boolean,
default: false
}
```

So if a person is registered as an admin the value will be true, otherwise, it will be false.

Every time when you are logging the users in, you can put an if statement under the `User.findOne()` query function to check if the admin field is set to true and therefore determine the type of users.

Furthermore, you should use the world collection in MongoDB instead of a table. It's a NoSQL DB.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive note about the difference between collections and tables. I am getting used to collections! But, the solution is not interesting. Adding a flag for separating different kinds of users does not seem wise! However, I am thinking about creating a hierarchy. It would be great, if I could separate the collections.

Comment: Creating 2 separate collections will also be fine. It just that every time you will have to check both.